# Can I connect my MacBook to my Windows PC via thunderbolt 3?

Tags: pci-express, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-networking

I recently built a PC where its motherboard support thunderbolt 3. However, it only has thunderbolt 3 header, so it comes to my mind to buy a thunderbolt PCIe card to connect my MacBook and PC together for them to share files. Is it possible? It would be a waste to buy an expansive pcie card if it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the model of Macbook ?

Comment: What is the model of the motherboard ?

Comment: @EchoMike444 MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) and the new B550 mobo from Asus, ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING

Comment: Thunderbolt will provide a connection, but what protocol will you use to actually transfer files over it?